# How to refactoring similar but not identical methods where one method extends the functionality of the other? C#

Tags: c#, methods, refactoring, dry

I have two methods which are very similar apart form the fact that the second method partially extends the functionality of the first method. For example the methods are below:

```
private void ExtendTable(FileInfo file, string columnToCopy, string columnNewName) 
{
    var data = File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName).ToArray();
    if (data[1].Contains(columnToCopy)) 
    {
       var content = data[0] + Environment.NewLine + data[1] + columnNewName + Environment.NewLine + data[2];
    }
}

private void ExtendTable(FileInfo file, string columnToCopy, string columnNewName, string secondColumnToCopy, string secondColumnNewName) 
    {
        var data = File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName).ToArray();
        if (data[1].Contains(columnToCopy) && data[1].Contains(secondColumnToCopy)) 
        {
           var content = data[0] + Environment.NewLine + data[1] + columnNewName + secondColumnNewName + Environment.NewLine + data[2];
        }
    }
```

As can be seen the second method slightly extends the functionality of the first. I plan on adding functionality which will print this back into a file, however my question is that this is quite repetitive and breaks DRY principle. How can I refactor these methods so there is less duplication while still ensuring they both work as intended.

Thanks

Comment: Use **optional arguments** to combine your two methods.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been suggested you could use optional arguments to combine your method. Another option might be to refactor the parameters into a `class` then pass an `IEnumerable` of that class to `ExtendTable`. This allows you to provide any number of `columnToCopy` and `columnNewName` to the method without having to modify it.

This snippet is untested, but it might look something like this...

```
public static void ExtendTable(string[] data, IEnumerable<ExtendTableData> extendData)
{
    if (extendData.Any() && extendData.All(ed => data[1].Contains(ed.ColumnToCopy)))
    {
        var content = data[0] + Environment.NewLine + data[1] + string.Join("" , extendData.Select(ed => ed.ColumnNewName)) + Environment.NewLine + data[2];
    }
}

public class ExtendTableData
{
    public string ColumnToCopy { get; set; }
    public string ColumnNewName { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you don't want to create a class and the version of .NET you're using supports it you could just use an `IEnumerable` of `ValueTuple<string, string>`...

```
public static void ExtendTable(string[] data, IEnumerable<(string ColumnToCopy, string ColumnNewName)> extendData)
{
    if (extendData.Any() && extendData.All(ed => data[1].Contains(ed.ColumnToCopy)))
    {
        var content = data[0] + Environment.NewLine + data[1] + string.Join("" , extendData.Select(ed => ed.ColumnNewName)) + Environment.NewLine + data[2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement one method also, with default parameters.

```
if (data[1].Contains(secondColumnToCopy)) 
{
    if (data[1].Contains(columnToCopy))
    {
         var content = data[0] + Environment.NewLine + data[1] + columnNewName + secondColumnNewName + Environment.NewLine + data[2];}
    }
    else
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

"params" is another option if the number of arguments vary.
Can get rid of 2 similar implementations.
Pseudo code below

```
private static void ExtendTable(FileInfo file, params string[] cols)
{

}
```